# how to do entries into database using Sequelize into junction table is there any need of model for junction table?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize-cli

How can data be inserted into a junction table in Sequelize ORM without creating its model, and subsequently retrieved using the "include" method for joins in Sequelize?

Comment: I later found it requires model for junction table